# Java/JavaFX Class Made of Instances of Another Class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm sure there is an answer to this already, I just don't know how to describe what I need to do in good search terms.

Let's say I am trying to make a program that handles the sale of unique pieces of wood (each has an ID) as well as tables made of those unique pieces of wood. I have two classes: WoodPiece and Table.

How should I create the Table class so that it can have instances of Table with unique wood pieces listed out so that you can add and remove the pieces up until the point the table is actually made and sold? Right now I'm thinking I make Table a subclass WoodPiece and it just has an ArrayList of woodPieces.

I'm not great at Java so I want to make sure I have the right idea before I waste a bunch of hours going backwards. Any tutorials you know of about this would be great. I'm using JavaFx for my program.

Comment: I think what you are looking to capture is that a Table is a WoodPiece, and also that a Table has a collection of WoodPieces. Is that right? If so, Google "Composite Design Pattern".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would construct the Table class using composition. A Table is not a WoodPiece, but rather it contains WoodPieces. In the future, a Table may have a tablecloth or people, etc.

```
class Table
{
    private Map<String, WoodPiece> woodPieces = new HashMap<>();

    public Table ()
    {
         // constructor
    }

    public void addWoodPiece (WoodPiece wp)
    {
         woodPieces.put(wp.getID(), wp); 
    }

    public WoodPiece removeWoodPiece (String id)
    {
         return woodPieces.remove(id);
    }
}
```

**Note**: I went with a map instead of a List since your WoodPiece object has a unique ID associated with it. Furthermore, I assume you don't care about the order of the woodPieces since a Table really doesn't have a natural ordering of the wood that composes it.

**Further reading**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Thanks! I ended up having to use an ObservableList because I had to print "woodPieces" out to a TableView, but this very much got me on the right path. Thanks for the Wiki link too!

Answer (score 0):

I understand with your description that I table is only made with unique pieces and is not possible to made a table with other tables. So you only have to add a List of WoodPiece to your table class and the add and remove methods.

In case you want to be able to make a table with other tables you should first create an interface (let's call it TablePiece) and both Table and WoodPiece must implement it and Table must have a List of TablePiece. In the following graph Component would be TablePiece, Leaf WoodPiece and Composite Table.
[image]